# How can I generate an BACKSPACE in a visual studio debug console?

Tags: c, visual-studio, getchar, putchar

I'm writing a Windows console mode C program using Visual Studio 2019 community. I want each backspace seen in the input stream to be printed as the *literal* string `"\b"` in the output.

How do you capture a backspace signal to the console? If I press CTRL-H it deletes the preceding character but I in fact what to getchar() to take the corresponding value.

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == '\t') {
        printf("\\t");
    }
    else if (c == '\b')
        printf("\\b");
    else if (c == '\\') {
        printf("\\\\");
    }
    else
        putchar(c);
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking '\b' is the back space chjaracter - what is to replace?  Ctrl-H is the standard ASCII CTRL sequence for backspace, it works in Windows cmd and powershell, but then so does backspace.  I have no idea whet "Visual Studio debug console" refers to.  Are you in fact using VS Code rather then VS?

Comment: It's `8` in Windows `cmd` console too. `printf("Hello%cu", 8);` outputs `Hellu`.

Comment: @Clifford, I hope I've made useful clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows console performs line edit processing on standard input allowing you to use backspace, delete, left/right cursor and insert/overwrite mode.  These characters and key presses do not result in a character being inserted into the input stream.

You can switch off the input processing using the Win API [`SetConsoleMode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode).  For example below I have switched of the processing and line-input mode so that `getchar()` returns after each character is entered:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE stdin_handle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); 
    DWORD console_mode = 0 ;
    if( GetConsoleMode( stdin_handle, &console_mode) )
    { 
        console_mode = console_mode & ~(ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT | ENABLE_LINE_INPUT) ;
        SetConsoleMode( stdin_handle, console_mode ) ;
    }

    int c = 0 ;
    while( (c = getchar()) != EOF )
    {     
        switch( c )
        {
            case '\t' : printf( "\\t" ); break ;
            case '\b' : printf( "\\b" ); break ;
            case '\\' : printf( "\\\\" ); break ;
            case '\r' : putchar( '\n' ); break ; // Translate ENTER into Newline
            default : putchar( c ); break ;
        }
    }
}
```

However it has probably undesirable side-effects such as causing ENTER to be interpreted as `\r` and for `getchar()` not to return when ENTER is pressed until after the next character is input.  No doubt there is a resolution for that, but I'll leave that for you to experiment.  It may be a conflict between what stdin processing and Windows console processing - and perhaps using  `ReadConsole()` and Win API console I/O functions in general would help?

Comment: Thanks for the direction, it helped.
I'm wondering if I were facing a similar task in *nix, how I could approach it.
Is there a non-standard C header or library for circumventing a *nix shell and it's line edit processing?
Maybe GNU Readline is such a resource.

The problem I was working, is an exercise from "The C Programming Language (2nd Edition)".
I'm presuming the designers of the exercise were working with a video terminal could hence just use standard (ANSI) C.

Comment: @Edmund That is perhaps a subject for a new question. SO is not a discussion forum, avoid run on questions in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution using the Win API and ReadConsole.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL readInput(HANDLE hConsoleInput, TCHAR chBuffer, DWORD nNumberOfCharsToRead);

int main(void)
{
    DWORD console_mode = 0;
    HANDLE stdin_handle;
    TCHAR chBuffer = 0;

    stdin_handle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    if (GetConsoleMode(stdin_handle, &console_mode))
    {
        console_mode = console_mode & ~(ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT | ENABLE_LINE_INPUT);
        SetConsoleMode(stdin_handle, console_mode);
    }

    if (stdin_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Error getting the handle to the console.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (readInput(stdin_handle, chBuffer, 1)) {
        ;
    }

    CloseHandle(stdin_handle);

    return 0;
}

BOOL readInput(HANDLE hConsoleInput, TCHAR chBuffer, DWORD nNumberOfCharsToRead)
{
    DWORD dwCount;
    BOOL bSuccess;

    bSuccess = ReadConsole(hConsoleInput, &chBuffer, nNumberOfCharsToRead, &dwCount, NULL);

    if (!bSuccess) {
        printf("Error reading from the console.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    switch (chBuffer)
    {
        case '\t':
            printf("\\t");
            break;
        case '\b':
            printf("\\b");
            break;
        case '\\':
            printf("\\\\");
            break;
        case '\r':
            putchar('\n');
            break;
        case '\x1a':                //EOF
            return FALSE;
        default:
            putchar(chBuffer);
            break;
        }

    return TRUE;
}
```